# Simple Copy Paste within a workbook matching program

Tags: excel, vba

This program prompts the users to select to folders. In one folder is the data to be copied, in the other the destination files. The files share a naming structure of 4 digit numbers "el numbers".

Everything in this code is working, except for selecting the data, copying it, and pasting it to the destination folder.

Currently, it is notifying me that I have successfully matched up the files, and that both are open. I've confirmed that the matches are correct and the correct files are open. The close and save functions are currently commented out.

I just can't seem to get the code to select the sheets at all. I've been trying to do a simple clearcontents using the code below and that didn't work either.

```
 Set myDatabook = ActiveWorkbook

 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").ClearContents
```

The most relevant code to the question is between lines of %%%%%%%%%, but all of it is included for troubleshooting.

```
Sub OPDwgUpdateFromMatchingSheetsELNumber()

    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ErrorYes As Boolean

' /////////////////// all OP Dwg opening and checks only\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    Dim MyOPDwgPath As String
    Dim OPDwgCheckSheet As Worksheet
    Dim FilesInPathOPDwg As String
    Dim MyOPDwgFiles() As String, FnumOPDwg As Long  'dim () string means array , the comma means the FnumOPDwg is used with it
    Dim myOPdwgbook As Workbook
    Dim elNumOpDwg As String`enter code here`
    Dim elNumOPDwgArray() As String, FnumEL As Long

    MyOPDwgPath = GetOPDwgFolders() ' call getOPDwgFolder functoin

    MsgBox (MyOPDwgPath) 'returns in msg box

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyOPDwgPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyOPDwgPath = MyOPDwgPath & "\"
    End If

    FilesInPathOPDwg = Dir(MyOPDwgPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPathOPDwg = "" Then 'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    FnumOPDwg = 0
    Do While FilesInPathOPDwg <> ""
        FnumOPDwg = FnumOPDwg + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyOPDwgFiles(1 To FnumOPDwg)
        MyOPDwgFiles(FnumOPDwg) = FilesInPathOPDwg
        FilesInPathOPDwg = Dir()
        elNumOpDwg = Right(Left(MyOPDwgFiles(FnumOPDwg), 7), 4) 'parse out just el num **MAY HAVE TO BE CHANGED IF NAMING CONVENTION CHANGES**
        ReDim Preserve elNumOPDwgArray(1 To FnumOPDwg)
        elNumOPDwgArray(FnumOPDwg) = elNumOpDwg
        'Debug.Print (elNumOpDwg & "  " & FnumOPDwg) 'print in debugging window press control + G to open
    Loop

    'Debug.Print (elNumOPDwgArray(3))


    ' //////////// data sheet check \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
    'Data
    Dim myDataPath As String
    Dim myDatabook As Workbook
    Dim myDataCheckSheet As Worksheet
    Dim MyDataFiles() As String, FnumData As Long ' array of data file
    Dim FilesInPathData As String 'location of data files
    Dim elNumDataSheet As String 'elNum parse from data file name
    Dim elNumDataArray() As String, FnumDataEL As Long

    myDataPath = GetDataFolders()

    MsgBox (myDataPath)

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(myDataPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        myDataPath = myDataPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPathData = Dir(myDataPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPathData = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    FnumData = 0
    Do While FilesInPathData <> ""
        FnumData = FnumData + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyDataFiles(1 To FnumData)
        MyDataFiles(FnumData) = FilesInPathData
        FilesInPathData = Dir()
        elNumDataSheet = Right(Left(MyDataFiles(FnumData), 7), 4)
        ReDim Preserve elNumDataArray(1 To FnumData)
        elNumDataArray(FnumData) = elNumDataSheet
    Loop

'/////////////////////end data retrieval\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
If FnumOPDwg > 0 Then
    For FnumOPDwg = LBound(MyOPDwgFiles) To UBound(MyOPDwgFiles)
        Set myOPdwgbook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set myOPdwgbook = Workbooks.Open(MyOPDwgPath & MyOPDwgFiles(FnumOPDwg))
        'Debug.Print (MyOPDwgPath)
        'Debug.Print (MyOPDwgFiles(FnumOPDwg) & "1")

        On Error GoTo 0
        For FnumData = LBound(MyDataFiles) To UBound(MyDataFiles)
        If FnumData > 0 Then
            If elNumDataArray(FnumData) = elNumOPDwgArray(FnumOPDwg) Then
                Set myDatabook = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set myDatabook = Workbooks.Open(myDataPath & MyDataFiles(FnumData))
                On Error GoTo 0
                'Debug.Print (FilesInPathData)


                  'Debug.Print (MyDataFiles(FnumData) & "2")
                    MsgBox (elNumDataArray(FnumData))


   '%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                    If Not myOPdwgbook Is Nothing Then
                        'Change cell value(s) in one worksheet in mybook
                        On Error Resume Next
                        With myOPdwgbook.Worksheets(1)
                            With myDatabook.Worksheets(1)
                                If .ProtectContents = False Then


                                    ' actual copy pasting done here

                                    myDatabook.Range("A1:DE31").Value = myOPdwgbook.Cells("A59:DE90").Value

                                Else
                                    ErrorYes = True
                                End If
                            End With
                        End With

    '%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                        If Err.Number > 0 Then
                            ErrorYes = True
                            Err.Clear
                            '    myDatabook.Close savechanges:=False
                        Else
                            '    myDatabook.Close savechanges:=False
                        End If
                        On Error GoTo 0
                    Else
                        'Not possible to open the workbook
                    ErrorYes = True

                    End If

                End If
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrorYes = True
                    Err.Clear
                    'myOPdwgbook.Close savechanges:=False 'Close mybook without saving
                Else
                    'myOPdwgbook.Close savechanges:=True
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

            End If
            Next FnumData
        Next FnumOPDwg 'iterate
    End If

        If ErrorYes = True Then
            MsgBox "There are problems in one or more files, possible problem:" _
                 & vbNewLine & "protected workbook/sheet or a sheet/range that not exist"
        End If

        'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
            .Calculation = CalcMode
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out all of the `On Error Resume Next` lines and run it again. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors before. I took it out and now I'm getting an error in this line.  myDatabook.Range("A1:DE31").Value = myOPdwgbook.Cells("A59:DE90").Value     The error is object doesn't support this property or method. I think taking those out got me a step closer though.

Answer (score 0):

The use of On Error Resume Next should be used sparingly and always be terminated by On Error Goto 0 (which you do). However, the lines:

```
On Error Resume Next
            Set myDatabook = Workbooks.Open(myDataPath & MyDataFiles(FnumData))
            On Error GoTo 0
```

should be followed by a check that myDatabook is properly assigned. If it is not the line:

```
myDatabook.Range("A1:DE31").Value = myOPdwgbook.Cells("A59:DE90").Value
```

will definitely cause an error.

Without analyzing your code I strongly suggest you follow Comintern's advice to comment out those lines.